# connecting dvd drive to an android device

Tags: android, usb-drive, cd, dvd

I am developing an android application for tablet in which i need to connect external cd drive and read the contents from the cd and display it in my app.

I am having a Asus external DVD RW [image]

I tried to connect it in my android tablet using USB port. While i connect it, there is a notification in my tablet like "Preparing sdcard",and after that there is a notification "Blank sdcard".

And how can i browse files in cd/dvd from tablet.

How can i read cd/dvd contents from the external cd/dvd drive.

Any one please help.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a written DVD/CD, then connect it again with your tablet and show if it shows "blank sdcard" or not